Could not create server TCP listening socket. bind: Address already in use. Processes won't stop, how to configure redis properly?
I was working with an ERPNext project, and when trying to install the hrms module, I ran into some redis related issues, and made some changes to see if those worked but it didn't. Now that I was able to install all modules related to the ERPNext properly and also I undo the changes that I already made with redis config to have the default values. Now when try to run the command bench start, it doesn't start server stating ports 13000 and 11000 are already in use. I searched and it was used by redis, I killed all the services that run on 11000 and 13000 but still it doesn't work.
Below is the issue that I encountered when trying to run bench start,
ransike@ransikevm:~/frappe-bench$ bench start
11:51:27 system           | redis_cache.1 started (pid=7357)
11:51:27 redis_cache.1    | 7359:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.348 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
11:51:27 redis_cache.1    | 7359:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.348 # Redis version=6.0.16, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=7359, just started
11:51:27 redis_cache.1    | 7359:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.348 # Configuration loaded
11:51:27 redis_cache.1    | 7359:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.348 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
11:51:27 redis_cache.1    | 7359:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.348 # Could not create server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:13000: bind: Address already in use
11:51:27 system           | redis_cache.1 stopped (rc=1)
11:51:27 system           | redis_socketio.1 started (pid=7360)
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.349 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.349 # Redis version=6.0.16, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=7362, just started
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.349 # Configuration loaded
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.349 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.349 * Running mode=standalone, port=12000.
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.349 # Server initialized
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.349 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.354 * Ready to accept connections
11:51:27 system           | redis_queue.1 started (pid=7363)
11:51:27 redis_queue.1    | 7373:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.353 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
11:51:27 redis_queue.1    | 7373:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.353 # Redis version=6.0.16, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=7373, just started
11:51:27 redis_queue.1    | 7373:C 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.353 # Configuration loaded
11:51:27 redis_queue.1    | 7373:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.353 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
11:51:27 redis_queue.1    | 7373:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.353 # Could not create server TCP listening socket 127.0.0.1:11000: bind: Address already in use
11:51:27 system           | redis_queue.1 stopped (rc=1)
11:51:27 system           | watch.1 started (pid=7382)
11:51:27 system           | schedule.1 started (pid=7372)
11:51:27 system           | web.1 started (pid=7369)
11:51:27 system           | worker_long.1 started (pid=7375)
11:51:27 system           | socketio.1 started (pid=7368)
11:51:27 system           | worker_short.1 started (pid=7399)
11:51:27 system           | worker_default.1 started (pid=7398)
11:51:27 system           | sending SIGTERM to redis_socketio.1 (pid 7360)
11:51:27 system           | sending SIGTERM to web.1 (pid 7369)
11:51:27 system           | sending SIGTERM to socketio.1 (pid 7368)
11:51:27 system           | sending SIGTERM to watch.1 (pid 7382)
11:51:27 system           | sending SIGTERM to schedule.1 (pid 7372)
11:51:27 system           | sending SIGTERM to worker_short.1 (pid 7399)
11:51:27 system           | sending SIGTERM to worker_long.1 (pid 7375)
11:51:27 system           | sending SIGTERM to worker_default.1 (pid 7398)
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:signal-handler (1721024487) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
11:51:27 system           | watch.1 stopped (rc=-15)
11:51:27 system           | worker_long.1 stopped (rc=-15)
11:51:27 system           | web.1 stopped (rc=-15)
11:51:27 system           | worker_short.1 stopped (rc=-15)
11:51:27 system           | worker_default.1 stopped (rc=-15)
11:51:27 system           | schedule.1 stopped (rc=-15)
11:51:27 system           | socketio.1 stopped (rc=-15)
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.456 # User requested shutdown...
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.456 * Removing the pid file.
11:51:27 redis_socketio.1 | 7362:M 15 Jul 2024 11:51:27.456 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
11:51:27 system           | redis_socketio.1 stopped (rc=-15)

Things I tried,
ransike@ransikevm:~$ ps -aux | grep redis
ransike      795  0.2  0.1  88644 11448 ?        Sl   10:49   0:08 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:13000
ransike      796  0.1  0.1  79428  9600 ?        Sl   10:49   0:05 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:11000
root        4215  0.0  0.0  27356  4992 pts/1    S+   11:00   0:00 sudo journalctl -xeu redis-server.service
root        4216  0.0  0.0  27356  1764 pts/2    Ss   11:00   0:00 sudo journalctl -xeu redis-server.service
root        4217  0.0  0.2 129952 16000 pts/2    S+   11:00   0:00 journalctl -xeu redis-server.service
ransike     7237  0.0  0.0  19808  2048 pts/5    S+   11:48   0:00 grep --color=auto redis
ransike@ransikevm:~$ killall redis-server


ransike@ransikevm:~$ sudo systemctl restart redis-server

I also tried bench update but that didn't work either. How to solve this redis related issue ?
